# SharePoint 2013 REST response: jasonObject.d.result is undefined but jasonObject.d is fine

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, rest

I am testing a SharePoint hosted app Menu Action.

I have written a REST call that brings back all the properties in a document item.

I get a valid response but when I unpick my response I run into difficulties

```
         var results = jsonObject.d;    // **note jsonObject.d.result is undefined**
```

Why is this? do I need  add anything to my http header or url

This has a knock on effect in that for each  below as 'e' is also undefined. I want my code to be robust an reusable - is there anything I need to do?

```
            $.each(results, function (i, e) {
                // ul.append("<li>" + e.Title + "</li>");
                itemHTML += "<li>" + e.Name + "</li>";
                console.log(e.Name);
            });

    // if not testing through the menu action
     itemurl = "/appsdev/Marketing lib/test.pdf";

     var urlItemAllFields = appweburl +
                 "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('" +     itemurl + "')/ListItemAllFields?@target='" + hostweburl + "'";


  setMessage(urlItemAllFields);


executor.executeAsync(
    {

        url: urlItemAllFields,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
            alert('Sucess');
            var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);

            var jsonObjectText = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
```

Comment: Can you share full code, the REST call, headers etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the reason why you are not getting the data in `jsonObject.d.results` is because you are explicitly asking for only one file. It is send only when a collection is requested like list items. Second change the REST endpoint URL not to have `ListItemAllFields`. You will be able to access the `Name` property also along with title. Your endpoint should look like this:

```
appweburl +"/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('" + itemurl + "')?@target='" + hostweburl + "'";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ahhh I was reusing a previous url request getting titles from a list. Your explanation makes sense .  Ok I still need ListItemFields as was to review all properties in my file .  I will just need unpick them from the json object another way

Comment: @westerdaled, you can mark the response as answer if you feel if it helped in resolving your issue.

Comment: no probs without you I would have been still confused here is my final code   var results = jsonObject.d;    // note jsonObject.d.result is undefined

                for (var resultProp in results)
                {
                    // ket the property (key) and it's value
                    itemHTML += "<li>" + resultProp +  ":" + results[resultProp] +  "</li>";
                    

                } which gives me a reasonable output